# How to fix ReactNavigation Error in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I was trying to implement the react-native navigation and I got the error "Looks like you have nested a 'Navigation Container' inside another..."

[The Error Image for the First One](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJEv5.jpg)

So I tried to fix it by putting independent={true} but it just quits the app and does not load. So I removed the NavigationContainer and I get the error "Couldn't register the navigator. Have you wrapped your app with 'Navigation Container'?"

[The Error Image for the Second One](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXd1q.jpg)

My Code is at the end of this question. The Navigation Container is at the end of the code.

How do I fix it? If somebody could help it would really help thanks in advance.

```js
<View style={{backgroundColor: '#010101'}}>
      <Header />
      <View>
        <Text style={{fontSize: 40, fontWeight: 'bold', marginLeft: 15, color: 'white'}}>Chats</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.thirdSec}>
        <View>
          <Text style={styles.textLeft}>Broadcast List</Text>
        </View>
        <View>
          <Text style={styles.textRight}>New Group</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
      <View
        style={{
          borderBottomColor: '#2b2b2d',
          borderBottomWidth: 1,
        }}
      />
      <ScrollView>
        <ChatList />
        <View
          style={{
            marginTop: 5,
            borderBottomColor: '#2b2b2d',
            borderBottomWidth: 1,
            marginHorizontal: 30
          }}
        />
        <ChatList />
        <View
          style={{
            marginTop: 5,
            borderBottomColor: '#2b2b2d',
            borderBottomWidth: 1,
            marginHorizontal: 30
          }}
        />
        <ChatList />
        <View
          style={{
            marginTop: 5,
            borderBottomColor: '#2b2b2d',
            borderBottomWidth: 1,
            marginHorizontal: 30
          }}
        />
        <ChatList />
        <View
          style={{
            marginTop: 5,
            borderBottomColor: '#2b2b2d',
            borderBottomWidth: 1,
            marginHorizontal: 30
          }}
        />
        <ChatList />
        <View
          style={{
            marginTop: 5,
            borderBottomColor: '#2b2b2d',
            borderBottomWidth: 1,
            marginHorizontal: 30
          }}
        />
        <ChatList />
        <View
          style={{
            marginTop: 5,
            borderBottomColor: '#2b2b2d',
            borderBottomWidth: 1,
            marginHorizontal: 30
          }}
        />
      </ScrollView>
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Tabs.Navigator>
              <Tabs.Screen name="Chats" component={Home} />
            </Tabs.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    </View>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I think this is what you want.**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { Header } from 'react-native-elements';
import ChatList from './ChatList';

function Home() {
  return (
     <View style={{backgroundColor: '#010101'}}>
      <Header
        leftComponent={{ icon: 'menu', color: '#fff', iconStyle: { color: '#fff' } }}
        centerComponent={{ text: 'MY TITLE', style: { color: '#fff' } }}
        rightComponent={{ icon: 'home', color: '#fff' }}
        />
      <View>
        <Text style={{fontSize: 40, fontWeight: 'bold', marginLeft: 15, color: 'white'}}>Chats</Text>
      </View>
      <View>
        <View>
          <Text>Broadcast List</Text>
        </View>
        <View>
          <Text>New Group</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
      <View
        style={{
          borderBottomColor: '#2b2b2d',
          borderBottomWidth: 1,
        }}
      />
      <ScrollView>
        <ChatList />
        <View
          style={{
            marginTop: 5,
            borderBottomColor: '#2b2b2d',
            borderBottomWidth: 1,
            marginHorizontal: 30
          }}
        />
        <ChatList />
        <View
          style={{
            marginTop: 5,
            borderBottomColor: '#2b2b2d',
            borderBottomWidth: 1,
            marginHorizontal: 30
          }}
        />
        <ChatList />
        <View
          style={{
            marginTop: 5,
            borderBottomColor: '#2b2b2d',
            borderBottomWidth: 1,
            marginHorizontal: 30
          }}
        />
        <ChatList />
        <View
          style={{
            marginTop: 5,
            borderBottomColor: '#2b2b2d',
            borderBottomWidth: 1,
            marginHorizontal: 30
          }}
        />
        <ChatList />
        <View
          style={{
            marginTop: 5,
            borderBottomColor: '#2b2b2d',
            borderBottomWidth: 1,
            marginHorizontal: 30
          }}
        />
        <ChatList />
        <View
          style={{
            marginTop: 5,
            borderBottomColor: '#2b2b2d',
            borderBottomWidth: 1,
            marginHorizontal: 30
          }}
        />
      </ScrollView>

    </View>
     );
}
       const Tabs = createBottomTabNavigator();
          function MyTabs() {
            return (
            <Tabs.Navigator>
              <Tabs.Screen name="Chats" component={Home} />
            </Tabs.Navigator>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <MyTabs />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Take a look at this snack:

https://snack.expo.dev/@devsaeedhabibi/navigationcontainer

**If this answer does not help,
Please provide more complete information about what you want.**

Please check the React Navigation document:

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-container/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hi Saeed, I want to create a bottom tab navigator but I always get the top error.

Comment: @Soorya Did you see the snack? https://snack.expo.dev/@devsaeedhabibi/navigationcontainer

I wrote a sample of your code and it worked this way, you can change it and check it out together.

Comment: @SaeedHabibi I fixed the problem by changing the code you gave me and tweaked it to fit me. Thanks a lot. Have a good day.

Comment: @Soorya Break a leg